# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource only for one request rest of API's are working fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have been trapped in very weird problem.

i have CORS configured on Nodejs backend using CORS package

```
const whitelist = ['https://www.domainname.co/', 'https://admin.domainname.co/','https://organizers.domainname.co/'];
if(process.env.env)
var corsOption = {
  origin: whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type",
    "Accept",
    "Authorization",
  ],
  exposedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type",
    "Accept",
    "Authorization",
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOption));
```

i have three frontend apps connected to same backend.

working on their respective subdomains

issue i am facing is everything is working fine but there is one specific API which is is throwing following error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.domainname.co/api/admin/event/add' from origin 'https://admin.domainname.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

strangely enough this works alright on my machine but my client has 2 different machines and it is not working on both of them.

and i am at loss from where to start debugging it.

I tried following things on client's machine via remote control.

1. use website in incognito on chrome.
2. use firefox.
3. use microsoft edge.

but everything ends in same result.

Comment: Can you confirm if endpoint you are facing issue with is placed after `app.use(cors(corsOption))` and domain is defined in `whitelist` array? Since code for routes are not shared, it is difficult to help.

Comment: @Raeesaa yes. 

domain is in whitelist. 

and all routes are after using cors configuration

Comment: Also, quick look at documentation for dynamic origin says that origin should be defined as function - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin. Can you update implementation for origin to a function and try?

Comment: I think that you don't have access to `https://api.domainname.co/api/admin/event/add` using `https://admin.domainname.co`. You have to add `https://admin.domainname.co` domain to `https://api.domainname.co/api/admin/event/add`

Comment: @IceManSpy that's what thought at first but i am able to call other APIs from same domain.

Comment: Thank you @Raeesaa i will update code on that and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const whitelist = ['https://www.domainname.co/', 'https://admin.domainname.co/','https://organizers.domainname.co/'];
app.use(
    cors((req, callback) => {
        const corsOption = {
            methods: "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS",
            allowedHeaders: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, x-www-form-urlencoded, Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept",
            exposedHeaders: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, x-www-form-urlencoded, Origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept",
            credentials: true
        };

        if (!req.get("Origin")) {
            callback(null, { ...corsOption, origin: whitelist });
            return;
        }

        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(req.get("Origin")) !== -1) {
            corsOption.origin = true;
            callback(null, corsOption);
        } else {
            corsOption.origin = false;
            callback(new Error("You are not allowed to access this resource"), corsOption);
        }
    })
);
```

You can pass a function to `cors` to configure when it is used by the app. This function will receive the request and a callback as arguments. You can set the `origin` value of the options object by checking if the domain exists in the whitelist. You can also ignore requests that don't have an Origin header set. Finally, you need to add `OPTIONS` to the list of allowed methods to enable pre-flight for HTTP requests that are not GET/HEAD/POST or have custom headers.

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything in comments and answer nothing worked because it wasn't a problem with nodejs or cors package instead it was problem with NGINX, nginx had default request size limit this particular request was exceeding that size. so to solve this i had to increase limit in

> nginx.conf

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

and my problem got solved.

Thank you people for your valuable time for devising solutions.